# M = L[i(1+i)k] / [(1+i)k-1] SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

Loan calculator

```
M = 0

L = raw_input("What is the loan amount you took? ")

i = raw_input("What is the interest for the loan amount? ")

k = raw_input("No of payments or years you are considering for this loan? ")

M = L[i(1+i)k] / [(1+i)k-1]

print("Your monthly payment is %f" %M)
```

Error:

```
M = L[i(1+i)k] / [(1+i)k-1]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're getting a `SyntaxError` because your syntax is completely nonsensical. What are you expecting `i(1+i)k` to do, exactly?! If you want a multiplication, you need to be explicit about that: `i * (i + 1) * k`. Also, note that your inputs are **strings**, not numbers, and you can't use different kinds of bracket interchangeably in Python (`[]` is for lists/subscription, `()` for tuples/calls). I **strongly recommend** you try actually learning Python's syntax before attempting to write code in it.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs man. I understood i am a fresher.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your inputs are strings or numbers, for multiplication in python you would have to specify the `*` between the values.

You should use `input()` if you a expecting the input to be only numbers or convert the `raw_input()` to int as `int(raw_input())`

The reason why you didn't get an error at

```
L[i(1+i)k] / [(1+i)k-1]  
   ^
```

Was because python consider `i(1+i)` to be a function call.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this. Although I'm confused if you want k to be decremented and then multiplied:

```
M = (L * (i * (1+i) * k)) / ((i+1) * (k-1))
```

or the denominator to be decremented:

```
M = (L * (i * (1+i) * k)) / ((i+1) * k) -1)
```

Also, you don't need to declare M = 0 as it has no use.